# getting 0 in Yii drop down?

Tags: php, yii

This is my yii drop down:

```
$dataForCountryDropDown1=array(
                            'india'=>'india',
                            'us'=>'us',
                            );

echo $form->dropDownList($myAccountAddress,'countryName', 
array ($dataForCountryDropDown1),array('onchange'=>'hideStateDropDownForm(this)',
'prompt'=>'Select Country','class'=>"drop-select"));?>
```

[image]

**I am getting 0 in drop down list.What is wrong here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nesting an array in another array (`array ($dataForCountryDropDown1)`). Try this:

```
$dataForCountryDropDown1=array(
    'india'=>'india',
    'us'=>'us',
);

echo $form->dropDownList($myAccountAddress,'countryName', 
$dataForCountryDropDown1, array('onchange'=>'hideStateDropDownForm(this)',
'prompt'=>'Select Country','class'=>"drop-select"));?>
```

Comment: Really It was crazy mistake. Thanks for it.